# Send a success signal when the group of tasks in celery is finished

Tags: django, signals, task, celery

So I have a basic configuration **django 1.6** + **celery 3.1**. Say I have an example task:

```
@app.task
def add(x, y):
    time.sleep(6)
    return {'result':x + y}
```

And a function that groups and returns job id

```
def nested_add(x,y):
   grouped_task = group(add.s(x,y) for i in range(0,2))
   job = result_array.apply_async()
   job.save()
   return job.id
```

Now I want to perform some action when that group of tasks is finished but if I put the the **app.task decorator** to **nested_add** and try to catch the **task_success** then it wouldn't work properly. Any tips of what I should use?

Comment: Have you tried chaining the group. aka make it a chord?

Comment: @user2097159, thank you i'm already reading into it i think that is it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are actually several options. The most simplest is to use chord. Chord will wail until all sub-tasks are finished with some result and then return the overall result back. More could be found http://ask.github.io/celery/userguide/tasksets.html. Another simple approach is to leverage AsyncResult API collect() method. More could be found here: http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/celery.result.html.

Don't forget to configure your result backend. more could be found http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting-started/first-steps-with-celery.html#keeping-results. If you are using RabbitMQ as a brocker then configure it as a result backend too.